# BGE: How to change camera's focal length?

Tags: python, scripting, game-engine

Is it possible to change camera's focal length
within the game?

What im looking for is that "Bow zoom in"
Or "warping".

Answer (score 3):

These two lines are all you need to change the active camera's focal length.

```
cam = bge.logic.getCurrentScene().active_camera
cam.lens = 90.0 #or whatever value you want
```

`bge.logic.getCurrentScene().active_camera` gets the active camera in the current scene.
Then `cam.lens` is accessing the lens attribute of the camera defined in line one.

Read through the docs about the [game camera](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_72_release/bge.types.KX_Camera.html#bge.types.KX_Camera), and you will see other properties you can get or set.

Do note that because *field of view* and *focal length* are related you can not set both `lens` and `fov` at once. Which ever value you set last will be the value that is used, and the other will be calculated for it.